# HTTP Status Code 500 Upon Accessing Localhost Project

Tags: apache2, lamp, localhost

I just installed LAMP on my Ubuntu and upon accessing a file which I am certain that is with valid syntax, I get the 500 internal error status code. I chmodded the directory for the projects (/var/www/) and tried nearly everything I could find on the web related to that issue.

A bit of information:

- I'm running Ubuntu 12.10
- I'm using LAMP
- I've cleaned my Apache error log so that to see the exact problem upon trying to access the project

  **[Thu Sep 19 21:50:17 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0**

  **[Thu Sep 19 21:50:17 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/backdoor.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in Unknown on line 0**

This also happens on small projects and is not related to the source code (that I'm certain about)

*Thanks in advance for any answers/solutions.*

Comment: The file is my creation and there is no 0 line in it.

Comment: It's a lot of code and private but I get the same error for the rest of the files on my localhost. Weird thing I noticed is the following in http://localhost/


**It works!

This is the default web page for this server.

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.**

How is that "no content has been added, yet" possible since I have MBs of project?

Comment: Have you check out http://stackoverflow.com/q/5326531/792066 ? Permissions should be 775 for the files..

Comment: Ah yes. I used to chmod the folder without the -R switch. Thank you, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

The files should have 775 permissions. I believe that it is not the case.

You should use `sudo chmod 775 /var/www/backdoor.php` or with baby gloves use the `--recursive` (`-R`) switch on /var/www/.